# Databricks Jobs REST API call does not work with Powershell

Tags: powershell, databricks, invoke-restmethod

So, here is the link to Jobs API call in Databricks [here](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html)

Everything works in Python using requests. E.g both the job creation and job listing works

```
import requests
proxy= "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
access_token="tokenabc"

proxies = {
"https": proxy,
}


header_read = {
'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token,
'Accept': "application/scim+json"
}

#list jobs
init_get=requests.get('https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/list', headers=header_read, proxies=proxies)

#create job
init_post=requests.post('https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/create', headers=header_read, proxies=proxies,verify=False,json=job_payload)
```

However, strangely in Powershell, only the job creation works and Job listing fails.

```
#this works
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/create' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $bearertoken" } -Method Post -Body $content -ContentType  'application/json'

#this does not work
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/list' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $bearertoken" } -Method Get

#RestMethod also does not work
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/list' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = "Bearer $bearertoken" } -Method Get
```

I have also tried setting the Content type on these but nothing helps.
Also, explicitly setting the proxy (fiddler) does not help.

```
-proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
```

But should not be the proxy also , as the post method works.

I just keep getting an error like

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:22 char:5
+     Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/ap ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

or in case of RestMethod

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:22 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://databricksworkspaceid.azuredatabricks.net/ap ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I could have understood if everything failed in Powershell, but the post method (job creation) works, so not sure, why the connection would be terminated in case of a Get request but not a post.

Going by some forum posts, I have also tried the following but to no avail-

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong/missing? Baffling to see working in python but only a part in Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally found the answer. Basically 2 things:

1. Had to do this before hitting the list endpoint (strangely as I said- the create endpoint) worked

Basically allowing TLS, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

2. Doing only point 1 didn't work. I HAD to also use an "elevated" powershell session. Basically running the script with step 1 included, using a "Run as Administrator".